# bring the colour widget to front in shiny app when using colourInput from colourpicker

Tags: r, widget, shinyapps

We use "colourInput" from the package "colourpicker" in a shinyApp for picking various colours.

When the colourInput is used by itself (# example 1 below), the widget pops up in the app and everything works fine (image 1 in attached figure)

It still works when we use splitLayout with the homemade "split_color_input" function (# example 2 below). However, the widget is now "hidden" inside a scroll-bar window (image 2 in attached figure). How can we Bring it to Front like in example 1?

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpPGO.png)

```
# example 1
ui <- fluidPage(
  colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = "id1",
                            label =  "label1",
                            value = "hotpink",
                            allowTransparent = TRUE,
                            returnName = TRUE,
                            closeOnClick = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


# example 2
split_color_input = function(n, id, labs, vals, allowTransparent){
  if (n%%2==1){
    colourpicker::colourInput(
      inputId = paste0(id, '.', 1+(n-1)/2),
      label=labs[1+(n-1)/2],
      value=vals[1+(n-1)/2],
      allowTransparent = allowTransparent,
      returnName = TRUE,
      closeOnClick = TRUE)
  }else{
    p("")
  }
}

id = "id2"
labs = c("label2.1", "label2.2")
vals = c("steelblue3", "hotpink")
cellwidths = c("45%", "10%", "45%")


ui <- fluidPage(
  do.call(what=splitLayout, args = c(lapply(1:length(cellwidths), split_color_input, id, labs, vals, allowTransparent=TRUE),
                                     list(cellWidths=as.list(cellwidths)),
                                     list(width=list('500px'))) )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick way to fix is to overwrite shiny's style `.shiny-split-layout>div {overflow: visible}`.

```r
# example 2
split_color_input = function(n, id, labs, vals, allowTransparent){
    if (n%%2==1){
        colourpicker::colourInput(
            inputId = paste0(id, '.', 1+(n-1)/2),
            label=labs[1+(n-1)/2],
            value=vals[1+(n-1)/2],
            allowTransparent = allowTransparent,
            returnName = TRUE,
            closeOnClick = TRUE)
    }else{
        p("")
    }
}

id = "id2"
labs = c("label2.1", "label2.2")
vals = c("steelblue3", "hotpink")
cellwidths = c("45%", "10%", "45%")


ui <- fluidPage(
    do.call(what=splitLayout, args = c(lapply(1:length(cellwidths), split_color_input, id, labs, vals, allowTransparent=TRUE),
                                       list(cellWidths=as.list(cellwidths)),
                                       list(width=list('500px')))
    ),
    tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout>div {overflow: visible}"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]